# how to use WithParam more than once in Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Hello i want to use two parameters in one line of query see example query down,

```
client.cypher.Match("(p:Person)")
             .Where("NOT (p)-[:KHOWS]-(:Person {Id:{param}})-[:HAS_PROFILE]-(:Profile {Id:{param2}})")
```

now how can i use `WithParam()` for both parameters in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either call `.WithParam()` 2x, like:

```
.WithParam("Param1", xx)
.WithParam("Param2", yy)
```

Or use `.WithParams`:

```
.WithParams(new {
    param1 = xx,
    param2 = yy
})
```

There is no performance difference between the two.